# What do the Stirling numbers of the first kind have to do with polylogarithms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, special-functions, stirling-numbers

On a whim, I had decided to look into ways of evaluating series of the form
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^k2^n}$$
which I learned has a more general form in terms of [polylogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html):
$$\text{Li}_k(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n^k}$$
Without prior knowledge of polylogarithms, I started working the sum where $k=1$. It's easy enough to evaluate by considering the derivative:
$$F(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n}~~\implies~~F'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\ge1}x^n$$
and so on, which tells me the sum is $\ln2$.

I noticed that I could keep taking the derivative in this fashion for larger values of $k$ and came up with the recursive derivative relation for the polylog (equation (18) in the MathWorld link). If I denote $f_k\equiv\text{Li}_k(x)$, then
$$\frac{df_k}{dx}=\frac{f_{k-1}}{x}$$
I considered successive orders of the derivative:
$$\frac{d^2f_k}{dx^2}=\frac{-f_{k-1}+f_{k-2}}{x^2}\\
\frac{d^3f_k}{dx^3}=\frac{2f_{k-1}-3f_{k-2}+f_{k-3}}{x^3}\\
\frac{d^4f_k}{dx^4}=\frac{-6f_{k-1}+11f_{k-2}-6f_{k-3}+f_{k-4}}{x^4}$$
I hadn't known about the Stirling numbers before this. As it turns out, the coefficients of the numerator's terms belong to [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A008275).

More generally, it would appear that
$$\frac{d^mf_k}{dx^m}=\frac{1}{x^m}\sum_{i=1}^ms(m,i)f_{k-i}$$
Is this result at all surprising?

**Edit:** For another thing, is it at all surprising that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m s(m,i)=0~~?$$

Comment: Just an aside: I don't think that $\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ has a nice expression for $n\geq 4$. The computation of such numbers depends on reflection/duplication formulas that gets messier and messier as $n$ increases.

Comment: Right, I had noticed that happening in Mathematica, each sum past $n=3$ defaults to the `PolyLog` expression. Considering my level of experience, I didn't expect to be able to find a closed form beyond $k=2$, if that, since I have no experience working with the Riemann zeta function.