# Generating Function for nth power of natural numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I was messing around with the geometric series, and upon differentiating and multiplying by x I got a generating function for the natural numbers (within a radius of convergence ofc).

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
By differentiating and multiplying by x each time repeatedly I found that this process could be extended to arbitrary powers of n, provided I could differentiate the associated function corresponding to that infinite power series. Is there a formula that yields the result after p such differentiations?

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}n^px^n=???$$
I tried directly applying the quotient rule and using partial fraction decomp. but couldn't spot an immediate pattern for the quotients in either function (I might have missed something though, as I only attempted this for a couple of powers).

Comment: With $f(x)=\dfrac1{1-x}$, the $p^{\rm th}$ sum is itself a sum of terms of the form $a_i x^{i}f^{(i)}(x)$ where the coefficients $a_i$ are [Stirling numbers](https://oeis.org/A008277). I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418608/what-do-the-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind-have-to-do-with-polylogarithms) (for negative powers $p$) a while ago

Comment: Your summation index $k$ doesn't appear anywhere. I think you intended it to be $n$ (in both cases)?

Comment: You're right, I just fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you express the power $n^p$ in terms of [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Connection_coefficients_and_identities),

$$
n^p=\sum_{k=0}^p\left\{p\atop k\right\}n^{\underline k}\;,
$$

where $\left\{p\atop k\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $n^{\underline k}$ is a falling factorial, and use the generating function of the falling factorials,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_nn^{\underline k}x^n
&=&
x^{k}\sum_nn^{\underline k}x^{n-k}
\\
&=&x^k\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\sum_nx^k
\\
&=&
x^k\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\frac1{1-x}
\\
&=&
k!\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

you obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_nn^px^n
&=&
\sum_n\sum_{k=0}^p\left\{p\atop k\right\}n^{\underline k}x^n
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^p\left\{p\atop k\right\}\sum_nn^{\underline k}x^n
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^p\left\{p\atop k\right\}k!\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

For instance, for $p=2$, this is

$$
\sum_nn^2x^n
=
\sum_{k=0}^2\left\{2\atop k\right\}k!\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\;,
$$

and with $\left\{2\atop 0\right\}=0$ and $\left\{2\atop 1\right\}=\left\{2\atop 2\right\}=1$, the generating function for the squares is

$$
\frac x{(1-x)^2}+2\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}\;.
$$

Comment: Whew, thanks for the answer: I'm only vaguely familiar with Stirling numbers, so definitely explains why I didn't see the coefficient pattern with partial fractions!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from what you've already done, the answer can be written in the form
$$
\frac{\text{some polynomial}}{(1 - x)^{p + 1}}.
$$
The coefficients of the polynomial in the numerator are the *Eulerian numbers* -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities

Comment: Another awesome solution: thanks! Lots of food for thought on the connection between the Eulerian and Stirling numbers.